# MikTex Console already running

Tags: miktex

I just installed MikTex to run LaTex on windows by following the instructions on [their web page](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex), but every time I try to open the MikTex Console, I get an error that the console is already running.

[image: MikTex Console is already running]

Any help with how to solve this is much appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you double-click to run it? Stop it with the Task Manager, and relaunch it with a single click.

Comment: Or perhaps you have minimized MiKTeX Console to the tray?

Comment: @Bernard I did not double click, I used the windows key and typed to search then clicked on the return button.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk I closed all the windows I had opened. Restarting the laptop fixed it.

Comment: It means that MikTeX is already running inyou system.
Although if you to stop it, You can open your Task manager and in processes tab you can select MikTeX console and click Endtask.

Comment: That's an annoying "feature" I also have almost each time I launch the Task Manager and then select to run as administrator. I guess the new instance loads before the running one is closed.

Comment: To avoid a double entry of answers See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473031/error-miktex-console-already-running/473060#473060

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved with a reboot mentioned in an comment.